# Show min and max value values mysql in php and namevalue?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to ask for help to display some information regarding queries made in a database.
I have a table called newtest.
In this table, I have 3 fields => (id, namevalue and num).
And in a query using phpmyadmin or adminer I can display the information neatly the way I want.
For example, I have the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `newtest`;
CREATE TABLE `newtest` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`namevalue` char(30) NOT NULL,
`num` char(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `newtest` (`id`, `namevalue`, `num`) VALUES
(1, 'X',    '10.55.1.100'),
(2, 'X',    '10.55.1.101'),
(3, 'X',    '10.55.1.102'),
(4, 'X',    '10.55.1.103'),
(5, 'X',    '10.55.1.104'),
(6, 'X',    '10.55.1.105'),
(7, 'X',    '10.55.1.106'),
(8, 'Y',    '10.55.1.107'),
(9, 'Y',    '10.55.1.108'),
(10,    'Y',    '10.55.1.109'),
(11,    'Y',    '10.55.1.110'),
(12,    'Y',    '10.55.1.111'),
(13,    'Y',    '10.55.1.112'),
(14,    'Y',    '10.55.1.113'),
(15,    'Y',    '10.55.1.114'),
(16,    'Y',    '10.55.1.115'),
(17,    'Y',    '10.55.1.116');
```

In a simple query using the command:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS MIN(`num`), MAX(`num`), `namevalue` FROM ` 
newtest` GROUP BY `namevalue`
```

I have the return:

```
MIN(`num`)  MAX(`num`)  namevalue
10.55.1.100 10.55.1.106   X
10.55.1.107 10.55.1.116   Y
```

However, when playing this in php and trying to display I have an error, the minimum and maximum values ​​of each 'X' and 'Y' are not displayed although the values ​​inside namevalue (X and Y) are displayed normally.
The following is an excerpt from the php code.

```
$myquery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS MIN(`num`), MAX(`num`), `namevalue` FROM `newtest` GROUP BY `namevalue`";
$To_info = $PDO->prepare($myquery);
$To_info->execute();



  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="info-box">
   <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
     <tr>
      <th style="width: 10%">Type</th>
      <th style="width: 10%">MaxValue...</th>
      <th style="width: 10%">MinValue...</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>

     <?php
      while ($VFor = $To_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
        echo '<td>' . $VFor['namevalue'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $VFor['num'] . '</td>';
       echo '</tr>';
       endwhile;
      ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

My result is:

```
Type    MaxValue... MinValue...
X   
Y
```

how can I load the minimum and maximum values ​​next to X and Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `MIN(num)` and `MAX(num)` won't be in your array as `$VFor['num']`. Try changing the query (naming the variables) to:

```
$myquery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS MIN(`num`) AS minv, MAX(`num`) AS maxv, `namevalue` FROM `newtest` GROUP BY `namevalue`";
```

then change

```
   echo '<td>' . $VFor['num'] . '</td>';
```

to

```
   echo '<td>' . $VFor['minv'] . '</td>';
   echo '<td>' . $VFor['maxv'] . '</td>';
```